# The most used + Noun VS Noun + is used the most

Tags: adverbs, superlatives

Are both of the following sentences grammatical and interchangeable?

> 'The' is the most used word.
>
> Word 'the' is used the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Close.

> *The* is the most used word.
>
> **The** word *the* is used the most

While the first sentence is grammatically correct, most English speakers would use an adverb:

> *The* is the most **frequently** used word.